# The future is in space?

Tags: riddle, outer-space

Here is a 'What am I' riddle...

I will go up but I **won't** come down?

There is a lot about me on the news

I will go up in the near future

What am I?

Comment: I've added the "outer-space" tag, feel free to remove it if it does not fit your riddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess:

> The applicants of [Mars-One project](http://www.mars-one.com/)?

I will go up but I won't come down?

> That's what will be going on there. The passengers will never return. No idea about the question-mark though.

There is a lot about me on the news

> For example, on [CNN](http://edition.cnn.com/2013/04/22/world/mars-one-way-ticket/index.html).

I will go up in the near future

> If you call 2026 near future.

Answer (score 3):

Is it the old classic

> A person's age in years?

I will go up but I won't come down?

> Obviously, a person's age just goes up as time passes

There is a lot about me on the news

> Often, if somebody dies, their age is mentioned in the news. Sometimes, in the case of celebrity, it's mentioned for any news article related to that person.

I will go up in the near future

> For everybody, their age in years will change within the next year.

Alternatively, it could be just

> The year it is now.

Comment: Sorry, that was a good answer but it is related to space.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I don't know much about it, but is it

> Some sort of Spacecraft?

I will go up but I won't come down

> Apparently some of them stay in the space (satellites etc.)

There is a lot about me on the news

> Space missions is always a big thing in the News

I will go up in the near future

> Some specific spacecraft that is scheduled to be launched soon?
>  [NASA Launch Schedule](http://www.nasa.gov/launchschedule/)

Comment: Yes your partly correct. Try to find the name of the mission

Comment: @SoRelatable Hmmm there's quite a lot of them scheduled, could it be Mars One mission? https://www.theguardian.com/science/2015/feb/09/mars-one-mission-a-one-way-trip-to-the-red-planet-in-2024

Comment: Sorry, someone got it before you. I'll give it to you though.

Comment: Oh, wait I can only tick one at a time sorry. T_T

Comment: Ok, nevermind :)